# Fill basket with items

Tags: product, cart

Hi Magento developers...

I'm having a bit of trouble with my new module. I created a simple module for people leaving their basket, without buying. I register every item put in the basket nice, with the observers in Magento. I then have a cron job running every minute and checking if a user has been inactive for 20 min. Then it send an email with a reference to a token in the database and here comes my failing bit.

I'm calling something like: www.domain.tld/add-to-basket?token=some_hash

I then retrieve all items from my database, with that token nothing hard here. But when I want to add then to the current guest cart it fails. I have searched the web thin and have come up with this.:

```
$session = Mage::getModel('checkout/session');
$quote = $session->getQuote();
$quote->setStoreId(1);

foreach($entries as $entry){
    $quantity = $entry->getQuantity();
    $productId = $entry->getProductId();
    $product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(['qty' => $quantity]));
}

$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

**Info:**

- I'm using oneStepCheckout
- Sometimes it works
- No exceptions are thrown (the code is wrapped in a try/catch)
- Have been debugging all the way (no errors or mystically values)

**Maybe:**

I think that the problem is, that the cart has not been initialized properly, when I try to add stuff to it, but I can't seem to find a solution for that.

Hope you can help.

// Ulrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I initialize the cart, then add all the items, then I set the flag of totals collected to false and then run save on the cart.

**The final code:**

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

foreach($entries as $entry){
    $quantity = $entry->getQuantity();
    $productId = $entry->getProductId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $cart->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(['qty' => $quantity]));
}

$cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
$cart->save();
```